# Select and concatenate DataFrame rows based on list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames like this:

```
df_cells = pd.DataFrame({
    'left': [1095, 257],
    'top': [1247, 1148],
    'right': [1158, 616],
    'bottom': [1273, 1176] 
})

df_text = pd.DataFrame({
    'words': ['Hello', 'world', 'nice day', 'have a'],
    'left': [1097, 1099, 258, 259],
    'top': [1248, 1249, 1156, 1153],
    'right': [1154, 1156, 615, 614],
    'bottom': [1269, 1271, 1175, 1172] 
})
```

`df_cells` contains coordinates of bounding boxes for phrases on an image and `df_text` contains words and their bounding box coordinates on an image.

I have created a list of tuples where the bounding boxes for phrases and words match based on `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` values like this:

```
overlap = [(0,0), (1,0), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

where the first element of a tuple is the index value of `df_text` and the second element is matching index value of `df_cells`.

I want to select,combine rows based on overlap into a new dataframe like this:

```
Words                df_cells.left    df_cells.top    df_cells.right   df_cells.bottom
Hello                1095             1247            1158             1273
world                1095             1247            1158             1273
Have a               257              1148            616              1176
nice day             257              1148            616              1176
```

and afterwards concatenate words with the same `left`, `top`, `right` , `bottom` like this:

```
Words                df_cells.left    df_cells.top    df_cells.right   df_cells.bottom
Hello world          1095             1247            1158             1273
Have a nice day      257              1148            616              1176
```

Would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: I don't understand what defines a "match". May you state the matching condition mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can assign the values directly to `df_text` with index created by list comprehension:

```
df_text.iloc[[i[0] for i in overlap], 1:] = df_cells.iloc[[i[1] for i in overlap]].to_numpy()

print (df_text)

      words  left   top  right  bottom
0     Hello  1095  1247   1158    1273
1     world  1095  1247   1158    1273
2  nice day   257  1148    616    1176
3    have a   257  1148    616    1176

print (df_text.groupby(["left", "top", "right", "bottom"], as_index=False).agg({"words":" ".join}))

   left   top  right  bottom            words
0   257  1148    616    1176  nice day have a
1  1095  1247   1158    1273      Hello world
```

Comment: Get the following error when runing your code (adapted for my actual dfs and list)



ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

Comment: Means you have more columns in either one of your df. Please always provide sample data that resembles your actual data.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I forgot to rerun a cell in my notebook after restart that deletes a column to make the number of columns equal.